# bootstrap5 navbar collapse don't has transition

Tags: css, sass, navbar, bootstrap-5, transition

i'm using vue3 and bootstrap^5.3.1

when closing or opening the navbar it works but without transition so this causes very annoying experience.
Demo:
https://wissam333.github.io/e-commerce/

navbar code :

```
<!-- eslint-disable vue/require-v-for-key -->
<template>
    <div class="appNavbar">
        <div class="padding_container" id="navbar">
            <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg">
                <div class="container">
                    <RouterLink to="/" class="logo navbar-brand">
                        <img src="../assets/logo.svg" alt="">
                    </RouterLink>

                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 navigation">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <div class="dropdown">

                                    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1"
                                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                        Shop By Category
                                    </button>

                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                                        <h5>Popular Category</h5>
                                        <div class="grid_container">
                                            <ul>

                                                <li class="itemes">
                                                    <RouterLink to="/ShopByCategory/electronics" class="dropdown-item">
                                                        <div v-if="mobile" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                                            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
                                                            <img src="../assets/furniture.webp" alt="">
                                                            <div class="wrapper">
                                                                <p>Electronics</p>
                                                                <p>240 Item Available</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div v-else>
                                                            <img src="../assets/furniture.webp" alt="">
                                                            <div class="wrapper">
                                                                <p>Electronics</p>
                                                                <p>240 Item Available</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </RouterLink>
                                                </li>

                                                <li class="itemes">
                                                    <RouterLink to="/ShopByCategory/jewelery" class="dropdown-item">
                                                        <div v-if="mobile" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                                            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
                                                            <img src="../assets/handBag.webp" alt="">
                                                            <div class="wrapper">
                                                                <p>Jewelery</p>
                                                                <p>240 Item Available</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div v-else>
                                                            <img src="../assets/handBag.webp" alt="">
                                                            <div class="wrapper">
                                                                <p>Jewelery</p>
                                                                <p>240 Item Available</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </RouterLink>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li class="itemes">
                                                    <RouterLink to="/ShopByCategory/men's clothing" class="dropdown-item">
                                                        <div v-if="mobile" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                                            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
                                                            <img src="../assets/shoe.webp" alt="">
                                                            <div class="wrapper">
                                                                <p>Men's Clothing</p>
                                                                <p>240 Item Available</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div v-else>
                                                            <img src="../assets/shoe.webp" alt="">
                                                            <div class="wrapper">
                                                                <p>Men's Clothing</p>
                                                                <p>240 Item Available</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </RouterLink>
                                                </li>


                                                <li class="itemes">
                                                    <RouterLink to="/ShopByCategory/women's clothing" class="dropdown-item">
                                                        <div v-if="mobile" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                                            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
                                                            <img src="../assets/headphone.webp" alt="">
                                                            <div class="wrapper">
                                                                <p>Women's Clothing</p>
                                                                <p>240 Item Available</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div v-else>
                                                            <img src="../assets/headphone.webp" alt="">
                                                            <div class="wrapper">
                                                                <p>Women's Clothing</p>
                                                                <p>240 Item Available</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </RouterLink>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <RouterLink to="/" class="nav-item">
                                <div v-if="mobile" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent">Home
                                </div>
                                <div v-else>Home</div>
                            </RouterLink>

                            <RouterLink to="WhatsNewView" class="nav-item">
                                <div v-if="mobile" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent">What's
                                    New
                                </div>
                                <div v-else>What's New</div>
                            </RouterLink>

                            <RouterLink to="DeliveryView" class="nav-item">
                                <div v-if="mobile" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
                                    Delivery
                                </div>
                                <div v-else>Delivery</div>
                            </RouterLink>

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <form class="d-flex">
                                    <div class="search_field">
                                        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search"
                                            aria-label="Search">
                                        <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </li>

                            <ul class="user_op navigation">
                                <li @click="router.push(toAccount)" class="Account_icon nav-item">
                                    <div v-if="mobile" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
                                        <i class="bi bi-person"></i>
                                        Account
                                    </div>
                                    <div v-else>
                                        <i class="bi bi-person"></i>
                                        Account
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="Cart_icon_to_miniCart nav-item" @click="openCart = true">
                                    <span v-if="itemCount !== 0" class="itemS_inCart">{{ itemCount }}</span>
                                    <i class="bi bi-cart-plus"></i>
                                    Cart
                                </li>
                                <RouterLink to="/CartView" class="Cart_icon_to_cart nav-item">

                                    <div v-if="mobile" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
                                        <i class="bi bi-cart-plus"></i>
                                        Cart
                                    </div>
                                    <div v-else>
                                        <i class="bi bi-cart-plus"></i>
                                        Cart
                                    </div>
                                </RouterLink>
                            </ul>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <!--cart managment -->
        <div class="cart_content" :class="openCart == true ? 'open' : ''">
            <div class="close_cart">
                <i @click="openCart = false" class="bi bi-x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="cart">
                <p>Subtotal</p>
                <p class="sum">${{ Subtotal.toFixed(2) }}</p>
                <RouterLink to="/CartView"> <button>Go to cart</button> </RouterLink>
                <hr>
                <div class="cart_wrapper">
                    <div class="cart_items" id="cart">
                        <div class="items" v-for="item in filterd">
                            <div v-if="item">
                                <div class="item_image">
                                    <img :src="item.image" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="price">
                                    ${{ item.price }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="delete_qty">
                                    <div class="quantity">
                                        <span
                                            @click="item.qty > 1 ? (item.qty = parseFloat(item.qty) - 1) : (item.qty = item.qty)"
                                            class="quantity__minus"><span>-</span></span>
                                        <input name="quantity" type="text" class="quantity__input" v-model="item.qty"
                                            min="1">
                                        <span @click="item.qty = parseFloat(item.qty) + 1"
                                            class="quantity__plus"><span>+</span></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="delete">
                                        <i @click="item.inCart = false; item.qty = 0;" class="bi bi-trash"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth"
import { useRouter } from "vue-router"
//store
import { getDataProduct } from "../stores/counter";
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
const getItems = getDataProduct();
const { filterd, Subtotal, itemCount } = storeToRefs(getItems);
//end store

// go to accountManagement.vue when user logged in and to LogInSignIn.vue if user not logged in 
const router = useRouter()
const auth = getAuth();
let toAccount = ref("/LogInSignIn")
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
        toAccount.value = "/AccountManagment"
    } else {
        toAccount.value = "/LogInSignIn"
    }
});


const openCart = ref(false);

onMounted(() => {
    // When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
    window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };
    // Get the navbar
    let navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    // Get the offset position of the navbar
    let sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
    // Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
    function myFunction() {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
            navbar.classList.add("sticky")
        } else {
            navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
    }
})

//solving navbar collapse problem 
let mobile = ref(false)
onMounted(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
        window.matchMedia("(max-width: 991px)").matches ? mobile.value = true : mobile.value = false;
    })
})

</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.appNavbar {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #a3d2e6;

    .padding_container {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
        z-index: 100;

        &.sticky {
            top: 0;
            max-height: 100%;
            background-color: #fff !important;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            box-shadow: 0px -8px 11px 0px;
            padding: 0;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            z-index: 10000;
        }

        nav {
            box-shadow: none;

            .navbar-collapse {
                justify-content: flex-end;
                background: #fff;
                border-radius: 30px;

                .navigation {
                    display: flex;
                    list-style: none;
                    align-items: center;
                    margin-bottom: 0;

                    .user_op {
                        display: flex;
                        padding: 0;
                    }

                    .nav-item {
                        padding: 10px;
                        margin-right: 15px;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        color: #000;
                        cursor: pointer;

                        &:last-child {
                            margin-right: 0;
                        }

                        .dropdown {
                            button {
                                border: none !important;
                                box-shadow: none;
                                text-transform: capitalize;
                                font-size: 16px;

                                &.btn.show,
                                &:active {
                                    border: none !important;
                                }
                            }

                            .dropdown-menu {
                                padding: 20px;

                                @media (max-width: 1200px) {
                                    padding: 0;
                                    border: 0;
                                }


                                h5 {
                                    position: relative;
                                    font-size: 18px;
                                    font-weight: bold;
                                    padding: 15px 10px;
                                    margin: 0;

                                    &::after {
                                        content: "";
                                        position: absolute;
                                        bottom: 0;
                                        left: 0;
                                        width: 100%;
                                        height: 1px;
                                        background-color: #000;
                                    }
                                }

                                .grid_container {
                                    display: grid;
                                    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
                                    padding: 10px;

                                    @media (max-width: 1200px) {
                                        display: block;
                                    }

                                    ul {
                                        list-style: none;
                                        padding: 0;

                                        &:first-of-type {
                                            margin-right: 20px;
                                        }

                                        .itemes {
                                            padding: 0px;
                                            margin: 0;

                                            a {
                                                padding: 10px 20px;
                                                display: flex;
                                                align-items: flex-end;

                                                .wrapper {
                                                    display: inline-flex;
                                                    flex-direction: column;
                                                    margin-left: 10px;

                                                    p {
                                                        margin: 0;

                                                        &:first-child {
                                                            font-weight: 600;
                                                            font-size: 16px;
                                                        }

                                                        &:last-child {
                                                            color: #666690;
                                                            font-size: 14px;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        .search_field {
                            position: relative;

                            .form-control {
                                border-radius: 30px;
                                min-width: 200px;

                                @media (max-width: 768px) {
                                    min-width: auto;
                                }

                                padding: 10px 20px;
                            }

                            i {
                                position: absolute;
                                padding: 10px;
                                min-width: 40px;
                                top: 0;
                                right: 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    .Account_icon {
                        display: flex;
                        align-items: center;

                        i {
                            font-size: 25px;
                            padding: 5px 10px;
                        }
                    }

                    .Cart_icon_to_cart {
                        display: none;

                        @media (max-width: 1200px) {
                            display: flex;
                            align-items: center;

                            i {
                                font-size: 25px;
                                padding: 5px 10px;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    .Cart_icon_to_miniCart {
                        position: relative;
                        display: none;

                        @media (min-width: 1200px) {
                            display: flex;
                            align-items: center;

                            i {
                                font-size: 25px;
                                padding: 5px 10px;
                            }
                        }

                        .itemS_inCart {
                            position: absolute;
                            font-size: 14px;
                            top: 12px;
                            color: #fff;
                            background: #013d29;
                            width: 20px;
                            display: flex;
                            border-radius: 50%;
                            left: 33px;
                            height: 20px;
                            justify-content: center;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .cart_content {
        border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        width: 150px;
        height: 100vh;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: #fff;
        transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
        z-index: 3;
    }

    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        .cart_content {
            z-index: 100000;

            &.open {
                transform: translateX(0%);
            }

            .close_cart {
                i {
                    padding: 10px;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
            }

            .cart {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 13px;

                p {
                    margin-bottom: 0;
                }

                .sum {
                    color: #B12704;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    font-weight: 700;
                }

                button {
                    background: #FFF;
                    padding: 0px 20px;
                    border-radius: 30px;
                    border-color: #D5D9D9;
                    border-style: solid;
                    border-width: 1px;
                    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(213, 217, 217, .5);
                    cursor: pointer;
                }

                .cart_wrapper {

                    .cart_items {
                        width: 100%;
                        height: calc(100vh - 127.7px);
                        overflow: auto;
                        overflow-x: hidden;

                        .item_image {
                            width: 100px;
                            height: 100px;
                            margin: auto;

                            img {
                                width: 100%;
                                height: 100%;
                            }
                        }

                        .delete_qty {
                            display: flex;
                            justify-content: center;

                            .quantity {
                                justify-content: center;
                            }

                            .delete {
                                i {
                                    font-size: 16px;
                                    padding: 0px 8px;
                                    cursor: pointer;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</style>
```

i tried a lot of things but none of them worked...
i want the bootstrap navbar to work smoothly in this project.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo. We don't need to sort through the entire web page and CSS file